# efficient loop of a map within a map c++

Tags: loops, c++11

I am attempting to find an efficient loop over a map data structure.

The map structure maps the following integers:

```
1 2, 2 3, 3 1, 4 1, 4 5, 5 3, 5 6, 5 7, 5 8, 6 4, 7 6, 8 9, 9 10
```

The resulting map looks as follows:

```
1| 2   
2| 3   
3| 1   
4| 1   5   
5| 3   6   7   8   
6| 4   
7| 6   
8| 9   
9| 10

Start : 4
Result : 
1(1) 2(2) 5(1) 3(2) 6(2) 7(2) 8(2)
```

Can anybody suggest how to efficiently loop (possibly recursive method) so that, given a start of say 4, the result would be

```
1(1), 2(2), 5(1), 3(2), 6(2), 7(2), 8(2), 9(3), 10(4)
```

So the idea is to use each inner key, as an outer key, starting with a given outer key. With outer 4 for example, the inner keys are 5 and 1. So use 5 and 1 as outer keys to obtain inner keys (3   6   7   8) and (2), the process should continue mapping the inner keys to outer keys. A running total should be kept per "jump". So it probably resolves to a recursive problem rather than a loop.

The process should stop if either you reach the starting point, 4 in the above scenario, or there are no more inner keys, for example, 10 has no mapping.

The loop starting at line 44, only performs the above, up to two levels, which is inadequate.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <sstream>

int digit_count(int number) {
  int digits = 0;
  if (number < 0) digits = 1; // remove this line if '-' counts as a digit
  while (number) {
      number /= 10;
      digits++;
  }
  return digits;
}

int main() {

  int v1, v2;
  std::map< int, std::map< int, int> > m;
  std::istringstream  stm {"1 2  2 3  3 1  4 1  4 5  5 3  5 6  5 7  5 8  6 4  7 6  8 9  9 10"};

  while (stm >> v1 >> v2) {
    m[v1];
    m[v1][v2] = 1;
  }

  std::cout << "Map layout " << "\n";
  std::string ss = "";
  int dc = digit_count(m.rbegin()->first); // equals max number

  for (const auto & p : m) {
    std::cout << p.first << ss.append(" ",  (dc - digit_count(p.first))) << "| ";
    for (const auto & val : p.second)
      std::cout << val.first << "   ";
    ss = "";
    std::cout << "\n";
  }

  int start {4};

  std::cout << "\nStart : " << start << "\n";
  std::cout << "Result : " << "\n";

  // efficient loop
  for (const auto & e : m[start]) {
    std::cout << e.first << "(" << e.second << ") ";
    for (const auto & x : m[e.first])
      std::cout << x.first << "(" << (e.second + x.second) << ") ";
  }
  std::cout << "\n";
  return 0;
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: Maybe I get your question all wrong but I can't see how `std::map< int, std::map< int, int> >` can hold the data described. To me `std::map< int, std::vector< int > >` seems a better choice.

Comment: Your input data is [an adjacency matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix) representation of a graph, and your problem boils down to finding a [shortest-path tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest-path_tree) for that graph, e.g. with [Dijkstra's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm).

Answer (score 0):

Took me a while, but I've answered my own question, and thought I'd update the post. The only way I could think of finding a solution was to create a recursive function. I don't think it is possible to achieve with loops. I didn't select Dijkstra's algorithm, since there are no weights to consider and  the results of this recursive function serve as input to a red black tree where each node of the red black tree holds a hash table (unordered_map).
So the result of the query on the combined red black tree/hash table is Log n, to find the shortest path. The problem is providing the input, as you can see from below, is recursive and inefficient.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <sstream>
#include <set>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>

int digit_count(int number) {
  int digits = 0;
  if (number < 0) digits = 1; // remove this line if '-' counts as a digit
  while (number) {
      number /= 10;
      digits++;
  }
  return digits;
}

struct vertex {
  int point;
  mutable bool visited{false};
  int id; 
};

void clear_visited(std::map<int, vertex>& verteces) {
  for (const auto & e : verteces) {
    e.second.visited = false;
  }
}

void traverse_graph(std::map<int, vertex>& verteces, const vertex & v, std::map< vertex, std::map< vertex, int> >& graph, int& counter) {
  if (verteces[v.id].visited)
    return;

  ++counter;
  verteces[v.id].visited = true;

  std::cout << v.point << "(" << counter << ") ";
  for (const auto & e : graph[v]) {
    traverse_graph(verteces, e.first, graph, counter);
  }  
}

void start_traverse_graph(std::map<int, vertex>& verteces, const vertex & v, std::map< vertex, std::map< vertex, int> >& graph) {
  if (verteces[v.id].visited)
    return;

  verteces[v.id].visited = true;

  for (const auto & e : graph[v]) {
    int counter{0};
    clear_visited(verteces);
    verteces[v.id].visited = true;
    traverse_graph(verteces, e.first, graph, counter);
  } 
}

bool operator<(vertex a, vertex b) { return a.point < b.point; }

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

  vertex v1, v2;
  std::map< vertex, std::map< vertex, int> > m;
  std::istringstream  stm {"1 2  2 3  3 1  4 1  4 5  5 3  5 6  5 7  5 8  6 4  7 6  8 9  9 10"};
  std::set<vertex> vertecesSet;
  std::map<int, vertex> verteces;

  while (stm >> v1.point >> v2.point) {
    v1.id = v1.point;
    v2.id = v2.point;
    m[v1];
    m[v1][v2] = 1;
    vertecesSet.insert({v1.point, false, v1.point});
    vertecesSet.insert({v2.point, false, v2.point});
  }

  for(auto & el : vertecesSet)
    verteces[el.id] = std::move(el); // dont need set objects anymore so move them

  std::cout << "Map layout " << "\n";
  std::string ss = "";
  int dc = digit_count(m.rbegin()->first.point); // equals max number

  for (const auto & p : m) {
    std::cout << p.first.point << ss.append(" ",  (dc - digit_count(p.first.point))) << "| ";
    for (const auto & val : p.second)
      std::cout << val.first.point << "  ";
    ss = "";
    std::cout << "\n";
  }

  vertex start {5,false,5};

  std::cout << "\nStart : " << start.point << "\n";

  start_traverse_graph( verteces, start, m);
  std::cout << "\n";
  return 0;
}
```